Why are the typical decay products of a fission reaction asymetric?
I am a fourth year undergraduate student. My nuclear physics lecturer made the offhand comment that most fission decays produce 'asymmetric' products. For example the decay of $^{235}U$ is:
$$^{1}_{0}\text{n} + ^{235}_{92}\text{U} \rightarrow ^{141}_{56}\text{Ba} + ^{92}_{36}\text{Kr} + 3\ ^{1}_{0}\text{n}$$ according to wikipedia.
The question is, why wouldn't we predict something like:
$$^{1}_{0}\text{n} + ^{235}_{92}\text{U} \rightarrow ^{118}_{46}\text{Pd} + ^{118}_{46}\text{Pd}.$$ In terms of the binding energy per nucleon curve:

It seems to me it would be energetically optimal to produce 'symmetric' decay products.

$2\times{}^{118}Pd$ total half-life is $3.8s$ while by-products of ${}^{141}Ba+{}^{92}Kr$ have total half-life of over $18min$ (or you can check $\text{max}(\text{group})$ half-life of the fission by-products). So it can be the fission tends to asymmetric decay, because at least one of by-product tends to have relatively high half-life (or even is stable). So that the rest are left "unbalanced". Intuition tells me that reaction prefers more stable elements, that's why. But I may be wrong.

If I remember correctly, it's because of the ratio of number of neutrons to the number of protons.
If you take a light element, the number of protons would be very close to the number of neutrons, i.e. 16O, 14N, 12C, etc. When you take heavy element, the number of neutrons is usually greater than the number of protons like 238U or 2O8Pb.
When you split the U atom into two smaller atoms, the ratio of neutrons to protons would become too great for these atomes. that's why you have asymmetric distribution of fission products.
I think this is it but again I'm not 100% sure...
